# How to find memory used by a particular job in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I need to check how much memory my job/task is using in hadoop. There are 2 jobs listed in `http://<my emr machine url>/cluster/apps/RUNNING`. I see Memory used (=16.5 GB) and memory total (=33 GB). I understand that 16.5 GB is used by both the jobs. Is there a way to find, how much memory each job is consuming in hadoop?